# Can Magento 2 handle REST updates from a Multi-threaded application?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a question regarding Magento 2's REST API.

We've developed an integration between a CounterPoint Database and a Magento 2 website. One of the bottlenecks in performance is updating product changes (inventory level, prices, product descriptions etc).  Currently, we update each product change one at a time.

My question is:

If we were to create multiple threads, and divide all inventory updates into these threads, would Magento 2 be able to handle this "water cannon" approach to sending it data?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I've recently testing this theory with Magento 2.3 and have found that it does not support it.  Whilst trying to update inventory I launched 10 threads and constantly saw the error:

{"message":"The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again."}

If only the Asynchronous Bulk API framework in 2.3 actually worked....